# "What badges can I earn?" on incorrect Privileges page

Tags: discussion, privileges

The [page describing approving tag wiki edits privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) (5000 reputation) has a section on "What badges can I earn?", which lists badges available for editing wiki posts. These badges can be earned before these privileges are achieved, so is there another page these should be moved to?

It confused me because it gave the impression that I could earn these badges once I attained those privileges, but I already have one of those badges..

Also, in the [Trusted User privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (20000 reputation) it describes writing and editing tag wikis, which users don't need 20,000 reputation to do. So should this be on this page too?

Comment: Tag wiki is not community wiki. You are confusing 2 different concepts

Comment: Yes you're right. I didn't realise that they were 2 different things. But, edits to tag wikis can be performed long before the approve tag wiki edits privilege is achieved.

Comment: **Editing** tag wikis and **approving tag wiki edits** are two totally separate things. You can **edit** almost anything on the SE sites, but the ability to **approve edits of other people** has to be earned.

Comment: @GlenThomas: While anyone can edit tag wiki, only trusted user (20k) can edit them without going through the review queue.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm aware that they are 2 different things. My point is that the page suggests that you need that privilege to earn the badges, which is not the case

Comment: As I said, you're misinterpreting what you're reading. You certainly can earn a badge by editing tag wikis before you have the *privilege*, because your edits have to be reviewed. You're still editing and working toward the badge, and can earn it before you've earned the privilege to edit without being reviewed.

Comment: @KenWhite I think you're misinterpreting what I'm saying. Forget the 20,000 rep trusted user privilege page for a minute, that's a separate matter. The "approving tag wiki edits" privilege plays no part in earning those 2 badges.